# How to make regex match pattern from the beginning?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a little assistance with a Regular Expressions.

I'm doing the following from JavaScript to "mask" all special URLs that may be composed using the following rule:

- They may begin with something like this `0>` or `1223>` or `1_23>`
- They may begin with a protocol, ex: `http:\\` or `https:\\`
- They may also have `www.` subdomain

So for instance, for `https://www.example.com` it should produce `https://www. ...`.

So I came up with the following JS:

```
var url = "0>https://www.example.com/plugins/page.php?href=https://forum.example.com/topic/some_topic";
m = url.match(/\b((?:[\d_]+>)?.+\:\/\/(?:www.)?)/i);
if (m) {
    url = m[1] + " ...";
}

console.log(url);
```

It works for most cases, except that "repeating" URL in my example, in which case I get this:

> 0>https://www.example.com/plugins/page.php?href=https:// ...

when I was expecting:

> 0>https:// www. ...

How do I make it pick the match from the beginning? I thought adding `\b` would do it...

Comment: use non-greedy operator `?` like so `\b((?:[\d_]+>)?.+?\:\/\/(?:www.)?)`

Comment: @alphabravo: Just missed a question mark, hah ;) Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make the `.+`, non-greedy, like this

```
m = url.match(/\b((?:[\d_]+>)?.+?\:\/\/(?:www.)?)/i);
```

Note the `?` after `.+`. It means that, the RegEx has to match till the first `:` after the current expression. If you don't use the `?`, it will make it greedy and it will consume all the characters till the last `:` in the string.

And, you don't have to escape `:` and you have to escape `.` after `www`. So your RegEx will become like this

```
m = url.match(/\b((?:[\d_]+>)?.+?:\/\/(?:www\.)?)/i);
```

Comment: Appreciate it! It's off topic here, but I'm always confused what shall I escape and what I shouldn't in regex. Is there a rule for that? And is it "bad" if I escape something like `:` when I shouldn't?

Comment: @c00000fd No problem :-) All the characters in the table [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_Special_Characters), are considered as meta-characters. They all have to be escaped, if you want to match them as they are. In our case, `.` has a special meaning in RegEx, so we escape it to treat that as a `.` character itself.